# Creating JPA from database

Tags: database, jpa, code-generation, dao, dto

I know this is a duplicate question.
But even i couldn't find any tool to create JPA entity file from database source.
I used eclipse to do this. I only got DTO kind of classes with getters & setters.
Can anyone suggest some tools that create DAO files too.

TIA

Answer (score 4):

You can use Telosys Tools, 
an Eclipse plugin working from an existing database with customizable Velocity templates

See: https://sites.google.com/site/telosystools/

Eclipse Marketplace : http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/telosys-tools

For JPA generation, use the JPA set of templates available on GitHub : https://github.com/telosys-tools

Answer (score 1):

you can use netbeans instead of eclipse. After you create own project, you can select "JPA controller classes from entity classes" in netbeans menu. For example http://ensode.net/roller/dheffelfinger/entry/automated_dao_generation_from_jpa

Comment: Dude are you for sure. Coz i'm going to download netbeans now.

Comment: "jpa controller classes from entity class" does not sound like what was requested in the question. Gugan ased for "entity classes from database schema", did not he?

Comment: you  can also find  "entity classes from database schema" near "jpa controller classes from entity class" in netbeans menu

Comment: No I didn't get what I want. Suggest me some other tools like Firestorm tool.

Answer (score 0):

[Minuteproject](http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/) is a generator tool and can generate [JPA2](http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/JPA2) artifacts from Database.

You can instruct the generator to apply convention for your java code that do not follow your DB convention, but the mapping will be correct. (Example strip DB name prefix; table starting with ADMIN_ such as ADMIN_ENVIRONMENT are Environment (w/out Admin) as java class) For the moment there 20+ conventions that help you reshape your model to be less DB look-and-feel by more Java-OO-friendly.

If you want DAO minuteproject has a track [BSLA](http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/BSLA) that generate spring-integrated DAO